# How many rooms in sandbox?

Tags: halo-3

I was playing Halo 3 ODST on sandbox last night. While I was deleting everything so I can make a huge structure for the Halo version of cops and robbers, I accidentally deleted a block and a hole was exposed. Out of pure curiosity I jumped down the hole. While doing this I thought jumping down the hole was a pretty bad idea. I know you can go above and below the main level. Is that all the rooms, or is there more?

Answer (score 1):

The level [Sandbox](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Sandbox) has 3 levels.

**Lower Level**

Referred to as [The Crypt](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Sandbox#The_Crypt)

> It can be accessed by removing the flat block in the center of the map (if you prevent it from spawning at start it will still be there and you can't delete it

It is essentially a large, enclosed room.

> The Crypt is 32 x 32 grid squares, which is approximately 16 x 16 single walls

**Ground Floor**

This is the floor you are likely most familiar with.  You can probably use it for medium-large maps.  The terrain is fairly flat, but the edges begin turning into hills.

This is also the level that the [Sandbox Skull](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Skull/Halo_3#Sandbox_Skull) is on.

**The Sky**

Known as the [Sky Bubble](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Sandbox#Sky_Bubble),

> This region can be reached via built-in teleporter in Forge

The teleporter, while not visible outside of forge, still exists.  If you get up there in a custom game, you will be teleported to the sky.

The sky is larger than the main floor (roughly 3 times larger).  It also has no features, so what you build is all that will be there.

Unlike falling from the Ground Floor to The Crypt, falling from the Sky Bubble will result in death.